# How do I put the data in the JTable in a new line but on the same row and why don't I see the horizontal scroll bars when needed?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have to put large amount of text into the `JTable`. When I try to put the text into the `JTable` , it all goes all into a row without breaking a line like :

[image]

and there are no horizontal scroll bars also. Is there any way I can put the text in a new line but on the same row so that all the data is visible.If you notice the snapshot there are dots at the end I cannot see beyond them though there is still some text to be displayed.

I have tried increasing the height of the row but that doesn't help.

*Note :* I have done this in the constructor :

```
jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Comment: *"I have done this in the constructor:"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to provide you're own table cell renderer.

Check out

- [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)

The issue you're going to have is updating the row height of the individual rows.  The `JTable#rowHeight(row, height)` method isn't tied to any model or renderer.

You can have a look at [JTable multiline cell renderer](http://blog.botunge.dk/post/2009/10/09/JTable-multiline-cell-renderer.aspx) for inspiration, but I'm not that keen on the idea of the cell rendered making decisions that may cause the table to re-render it-self.

You could override the `prepareRenderer` method of the `JTable` to do this, but that's getting pretty dirty to

Comment: I added the code (see the edits) to add horizontal bar automatically but then the horizontal scroll bar doesn't appear !

Comment: The default cell render is just a `JLabel`.  When it runs out of room to display the text it displays "..." to indicate the value over filled the area available to it.  To get this to work, you're going to have to go to the column model and update the widths of the column to meet your requirements, but this is not a trivial task

Answer (score 1):

You might use HTML formatting in am HTML component such as `JLabel` (the default renderer) or use a multi-line component such as `JTextArea` to render the content.

See also [How to use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: and what could be the reason I do not see the horizontal scroll bars ?